# Elixir Ecto - many-to-many relationship query with wrong column

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this table `Chatactions`:

```
defmodule Module.Chats.Chataction do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias Module.Chats.ChatactionReadat 
  alias Module.Users.User

  schema "chatactions" do
    field :action, :string
    ...
    many_to_many :readat, ChatactionReadat, join_through: "chataction_readat"
    belongs_to(:user, User, primary_key: true)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(chat_action, attrs) do
    chat_action
    ...
  end
end
```

and `chataction_readat`:

```
defmodule Module.Chats.ChatactionReadat do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias Module.Chats.Chataction
  alias Module.Users.User

  @primary_key false
  schema "chataction_readat" do
    belongs_to(:chataction, Chataction, primary_key: true)
    belongs_to(:user, User, primary_key: true)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(chataction_readat, attrs) do
    chataction_readat 
    |> cast(attrs, [:chataction_id, :user_id])
    |> validate_required([:chataction_id, :user_id])
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:chataction_id)
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:user_id)
  end
end
```

but when I query `chataction` with `preload`:

```
#Module.Chats
  def get_chatactions_by(:channel, channel) do
    q =
      from a in Chataction,
        where: a.channel == ^channel,
        order_by: [:inserted_at]

    a =  Repo.all(q)
          |> Repo.preload(:readat)

  end
```

I got an error:

> (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column) column
> c1.chataction_readat_id does not exist

I kind of expect the `preload` to look for `chataction_id` rather than `chataction_readat_id`.

I am not sure which part of the setting gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be your `ChatactionReadat` that because you've set the `chataction` as primary key, which i think should not be done as it's a foreign key should not act as primary key. I'm not sure about it but from the error it looks like that is the issue.

You can try the following:

1. Remove `@primary_key false` from `ChatactionReadat` schema Remove
2. `primary_key: true` form the relation in that schema